# Can I prevent the IOException from opening the messagebox?

Tags: c#, .net, io, .net-4.5

*//Note1: some localized message was translated directly, so it will probably be diffferent on your computer, but the meaning is the same.

//Note2: this program is build under .NET Framework 4.5, Release, x64.*
I am designing a program that can backup the flash drive silently and automatically.
In the copy method, I use code like:

```cs
        //Note: the Cout(string) method is a logging method, acturally equivalent to Console.WriteLine(string)
        public void CopyMoveDisk(string fromdir, string todir, int times = 0)
        {
            try
            {
                if (PauseToken)
                {
                    Cout("Copy: paused");
                    STTimer t = new STTimer(o => { CopyMoveDisk(fromdir, todir, times); }, null, 5000, -1);
                    Thread.Sleep(6000);
                    t.Dispose();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!Directory.Exists(todir))
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(todir);
                        var filessmall = from f in Directory.GetFiles(fromdir)
                                         where new FileInfo(f).Length <= 100 * Math.Pow(2, 20)
                                         orderby new FileInfo(f).Length
                                         select f;
                        var filesbig = from f in Directory.GetFiles(fromdir)
                                       where new FileInfo(f).Length > 100 * Math.Pow(2, 20)
                                       orderby new FileInfo(f).Length
                                       select f;

                        Cout("Copy: small file region");
                        // Copy the small files (<= 100MiB)
                        foreach (string file in filessmall)
                        {
                            s.CopyingFile = todir + Path.GetFileName(file);
                            if (File.Exists(todir + Path.GetFileName(file)))
                            {
                                if (new FileInfo(file).Length != new FileInfo(todir + Path.GetFileName(file)).Length)
                                {
                                    Cout($"Copy true: {file} => {todir + Path.GetFileName(file)}: Length = {new FileInfo(todir + Path.GetFileName(file)).Length}");
                                    File.Copy(file, todir + Path.GetFileName(file), true);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Cout($"Exist: {file} => {todir + Path.GetFileName(file)}: Length = {new FileInfo(todir + Path.GetFileName(file)).Length}");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Cout($"Copy: {file} => {todir + Path.GetFileName(file)}");
                                File.Copy(file, todir + Path.GetFileName(file), true);
                            }
                            s.CopyingFile = string.Empty;
                        }
                        Cout("Copy: small file region end");

                        Cout($"Copy: directory region: {times} time(s)");
                        // Copy the sub directories
                        foreach (string sub in Directory.GetDirectories(fromdir))
                        {
                            if (!sub.Contains("System Volume Information"))
                            {
                                Cout($"Copy: {sub + "\\"} => {todir + Path.GetFileName(sub) + "\\"}");
                                CopyMoveDisk(sub + "\\", todir + Path.GetFileName(sub) + "\\", times + 1);
                            }
                        }
                        Cout($"Copy: directory region end: {times} time(s)");

                        Cout("Copy: big file region");
                        // Copy the big files (> 100MiB)
                        foreach (string file in filesbig)
                        {
                            s.CopyingFile = todir + Path.GetFileName(file);
                            if (File.Exists(todir + Path.GetFileName(file)))
                            {
                                if (new FileInfo(file).Length != new FileInfo(todir + Path.GetFileName(file)).Length)
                                {
                                    Cout($"Copy true: {file} => {todir + Path.GetFileName(file)}: Length = {new FileInfo(todir + Path.GetFileName(file)).Length}");
                                    File.Copy(file, todir + Path.GetFileName(file), true);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Cout($"Exist: {file} => {todir + Path.GetFileName(file)}: Length = {new FileInfo(todir + Path.GetFileName(file)).Length}");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Cout($"Copy: {file} => {todir + Path.GetFileName(file)}");
                                File.Copy(file, todir + Path.GetFileName(file), true);
                            }
                            s.CopyingFile = string.Empty;
                        }
                        Cout("Copy: big file region end");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Cout($"Copy: -----Exception {ex} {Environment.NewLine}----------");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Cout($"Copy: -----Exception {ex} {Environment.NewLine}{s}{Environment.NewLine}----------");
            }
        }
```

After viewing the code, let's imagine a situation:
The user insert a SD Card reader. When the files are copying, the SD Card somehow become disconnected but the reader remains inserted (probably because of poor contact).
Whenever you inserted a Card reader without a card, the Windows Explorer will warn you with "Please insert the disk into 'SD Card (E:\)'."
But when this situation happened to be on this program, the method didn't throw the exception immerdiately. Instead, it showed a messagebox like:

> |---USBBackup.exe - No disks|
> | There're no disks in the drive. Please insert the disk in the drive E: |
> |Cancel| |Retry| |Continue|

If I clicked the cancel button (or the continue button?) then will throw an exception:

> System.IO.IOException: The floppy disk in the drive is not correct.
> Insert %2 (volume serial number: %3) to drive %1.
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
> at USBBackup.Form1.CopyMoveDisk(String fromdir, String todir, Int32 times)

***//Note3: Somehow the messagebox won't show on my Windows 10 VM.

//Instead, it will throw a excetion directly:***

> System.IO.IOException: The device is not ready.
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
> at USBBackup.Form1.CopyMoveDisk(String fromdir, String todir, Int32 times)

***//But it showed on my Windows 7 VM.

//Or probably because I installed the .Net Framework 4.8 on the Win10 VM, but 4.5 on the Win7 VM.***
Now that I don't want this program to disturb the user, what can I do to avoid showing the messagebox?

Comment: Yes. Because of the try-catch block, I think it should not show a message box. It's not the normal JIT Debug message box. Please read the whole article again.

Comment: The problem is solved.  Acturally I hope you to write a formal answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to call the [SetErrorMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-seterrormode) API with  `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` to disable the system messageboxes and set it back afterwards.
Create an internal class `NativeMethods`:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern ErrorModes SetErrorMode(ErrorModes uMode);

    [Flags]
    internal enum ErrorModes : uint 
    {
        SYSTEM_DEFAULT             = 0x0,
        SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS     = 0x0001,
        SEM_NOALIGNMENTFAULTEXCEPT = 0x0004,
        SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX      = 0x0002,
        SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX     = 0x8000
    }
}
```

An example usage:

```
void BackupFiles()
{
    var prevMode = NativeMethods.SetErrorMode(NativeMethods.SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
    try
    {
        // attempt to copy the files
        // from the removable device
    }
    finally
    {
        NativeMethods.SetErrorMode(prevMode);
    }
}
```